# Creating Bilateral migration Matrix in Stata or R

Tags: r, networking, migration, stata

My data is similar to table given below. I have data to province where an individual is living and data on previous province where he was living last year. I want to construct the outflow rate and inflow rate of migrants in Stata or R

| Province | Previous Province |
| --- | --- |
| Delhi | Mumbai |
| Mumbai | Kolkata |
| Kolkata | Mumbai |
| Delhi | Mumbai |
| Kolkata | Delhi |
| Mumbai | Mumbai |

I want a matrix which is as follows

|  | Delhi | Mumbai | Kolkata |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Delhi | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| Mumbai | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| Kolkata | 1 | 1 | 0 |

Comment: Can you provide any code you've tried out so far, even if it ends in an error message?

Answer (score 0):

```
table(df)
         Previous_Province
Province  Delhi Kolkata Mumbai
  Delhi       0       0      2
  Kolkata     1       0      1
  Mumbai      0       1      1
```

In dataframe format:

```
as.data.frame.matrix(table(df))

        Delhi Kolkata Mumbai
Delhi       0       0      2
Kolkata     1       0      1
Mumbai      0       1      1

pivot_wider(df, names_from = Previous_Province, 
             values_from = Previous_Province, values_fn = length, 
             values_fill = 0)
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  Province Mumbai Kolkata Delhi
  <chr>     <int>   <int> <int>
1 Delhi         2       0     0
2 Mumbai        1       1     0
3 Kolkata       1       0     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example in Stata. First input the data (I added a `move_indicator` variable to save me a line below!):

```
clear
input str10(Province Previous_Province) move_indicator 
"Delhi"      "Mumbai" 1
"Mumbai"    "Kolkata" 1
"Kolkata"   "Mumbai" 1
"Delhi"     "Mumbai" 1
"Kolkata"   "Delhi" 1
"Mumbai"    "Mumbai" 1
end
```

Then:

```
// Collapse to count moves for each pair of Province-PreviousProvince 
collapse (sum) N_=move_indicator, by(Province Previous_Province)

// Reshape so that each previous province becomes a column 
reshape wide N_, j(Previous_Province) i(Province) string

// Replace zeros with missing
foreach var of varlist N_* {
    replace `var' = 0 if missing(`var')
}
```

Here we verify that it matches the output you wanted:

```
* Order and sort to match your example 
sort Province
order Province N_Delhi N_Mumbai N_Kolkata 
list
```

The `list` output is below:

```
     +------------------------------------------+
     | Province   N_Delhi   N_Mumbai   N_Kolk~a |
     |------------------------------------------|
  1. |    Delhi         0          2          0 |
  2. |  Kolkata         1          1          0 |
  3. |   Mumbai         0          1          1 |
     +------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: If I want to calculate the migration rate along with the occupation, age and education characteristics, then how should I change  my state code.